# Compilation error when trying to build R Studio server on gentoo server

Tags: r, rstudio-server, gentoo

I am trying to build and install RStudio server on my gentoo server. getting error:

> CMake Error at src/gwt/CMakeLists.txt:70 (message):
> ant not found (required to build GWT)

[snapshot of compilation error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LOu2X.png)

Comment: One really provokes these kinds of errors in using gentoo... Note also that RStudio server [does not test and certify builds on gentoo](https://www.rstudio.com/products/rstudio/download-server/other-platforms/).

Comment: ant is a Java-based buildsystem. Have you installed `dev-java/ant`?

Comment: ant is not installed, I checked with "ant -version".
will install and check